# How can i have various configuration in nagios config file

Tags: linux, centos, nagios, log-files

I am using nagios `check_logfiles` plugin from here

http://labs.consol.de/lang/en/nagios/check_logfiles/

I have the config file like this

```
@searches = (
  {
    tag => 'san',
    logfile => '/var/adm/messages',
    criticalpatterns => [
        'Link Down Event received',
        'Loop OFFLINE',
        'fctl:.*disappeared from fabric',
        '.*Lun.*disappeared.*'
    ],
  },
);
```

and using with

`/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_logfiles -f /etc/nagios/objects/logfile.cfg`

But i want to monitor 6-7 log files. so i want to ask that can i add the same snippet for many log files with different patterns in `logfile.cfg` or i have to make separate file for each

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a different conf file for each different run of check_logfiles, make a command def like this:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_logfiles -f /etc/nagios/objects/$ARG1$
```

And then your command_line in the service definitions would be something like:

```
check_logfiles!logfile1.cfg
check_logfiles!logfile2.cfg
```

etc.

Or check out the *–searches* flag to check_logfiles; this allows you to use multiple check_logfiles conf snippets in the same config file, each with a unique search tag.

Comment: i could find in their docs to specify `search label` and then how to use that label. can you give me some example

Comment: From the page you linked to, under Features: "–searches=<tag1,tag2,…> A list of tags of those searches which are to be run. Using this parameter, not all searches listed in the config file are run, but only those selected. (–selectedsearches is also possible)"